# JQuery How to Quote a Dynamic String

Tags: jquery

I have two form elements.  One is a drop-down list that is dynamically populated via a getJSON call.  The other is a standard input text box.

When the form loads, the drop-down list gets populated.  The text box will 'usually' have a value in it, as this is an approval form.

What I'm trying to do is have the value in my drop-down list that matches the value in the text box be the selected option. This works for me with other drop-downs of this type, but in this case, I think I have a problem with spaces in my drop-down values and in my text box value.

In the problem I'm having, my text box has a value of "Big Red Barn". (no quotes)
One of the values in my drop-down list also has a value of "Big Red Barn". (no quotes)  This should be the selected one.

Form:

```
<select name="cu_vendors" id="cu_vendors">
</select>

<input type="text" name="ven_name" id="ven_name" />
```

My drop-down list populates just fine.

JQuery:

```
$.getJSON("get-cu-vendors.html", function(data){
  $('#cu_vendors').html('');
  if(data && data.length > 0){
    $('#cu_vendors').append("<option value='' class='red'>Required</option>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $("#cu_vendors").append("<option value=\""+$.trim(value)+"\">"+value+"</option>");                  
    });         
  }else{
   $('#cu_vendors').html('');
  }
});
 $("#cu_vendors option[value="+ $('#ven_name').val() +"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

I get a syntax error, but not what it is:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #cu_vendors option[value=Big Red Barn]
```

So, I'm thinking the spaces are the issue here.   Is there a way in JQuery to quote these values when I use $('#ven_name').val() in my last line above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to have the following $("#cu_vendors option[value='"+ $('#ven_name').val() +"']")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.. First, the line that sets the selected option needs to be inside the `$.getJSON` callback or it will execute before the ajax call finishes. Second, Since the value in your selector has spaces, that value needs to be quoted:

```
$.getJSON("get-cu-vendors.html", function (data) {
    $('#cu_vendors').html('');
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        $('#cu_vendors').append("<option value='' class='red'>Required</option>");
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#cu_vendors").append("<option value=\"" + $.trim(value) + "\">" + value + "</option>");
        });
        $("#cu_vendors option[value='" + $('#ven_name').val() + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        $('#cu_vendors').html('');
    }    
});
```

You can see from your error message that your selector looks like this:

```
#cu_vendors option[value=Big Red Barn]
```

When it needs to look like this:

```
#cu_vendors option[value="Big Red Barn"]
```

Comment: Thank You Jason P.  That was it.  The other answers were correct also, but putting the select line inside the jason call worked.  I had not noticed I put it outside the json block.  I should have looked more closely to other areas where I've used this.  None of those drop-downs have spaces so I was blinded by that I think.  Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#cu_vendors option[value='"+ $('#ven_name').val() +"']")
```

should do the trick.

No problem with spaces !

Notice the use of **'** : you want to have **"value='thing with spaces'"** and not "value=thing with spaces".

Also, as someone has already said now, you can see it from your error message that simple quotes are missing.

Comment: Thanks.  That stopped the syntax error, but it sill wont set the value in my drop-down list that matches Big Red Barn.  Would the spaces in my drop-down list also be the issue?  Maybe I'll have to re-factor my db values and code to use non-spaces in the values behind what shows on the form.  Sigh!

Comment: Sorry I did not consider your whole problem. Seems you have found the solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing quotes around the selector:

```
$("#cu_vendors option[value='"+ $('#ven_name').val() +"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```